# MySQL UPDATE value in SQLfiddle

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I've just started on SQL and so far I've made this and it works

```
CREATE TABLE employees(employee_ID int NOT NULL, name varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
                   PRIMARY KEY (employee_ID)
                  );
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(1, 'Adam Jones');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(2, 'Amy Smith');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(3, 'Anthony Wright');

CREATE TABLE department(department_ID varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
                    department_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, head_of_dep varchar(20), 
                    num_of_employees_in_dep int
                   );
INSERT INTO department VALUES('Bad At SQL Ltd', 'Need Help HQ', 'No One Yet', 3);
```

But I cant understand why this wont work

```
UPDATE department SET head_of_dep = name FROM employees WHERE employee_ID = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using SQLfiddle and MySQL 5.5.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite it to

```
UPDATE department SET head_of_dep = (SELECT name FROM employees WHERE employee_ID = 1)
```

because you actually have to `SELECT` the value